# How to keep input results after refreshing with javascript and localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I am making a Book Listing App with Javascript ,however I want to keep all input result on html webpage, even if webpage is refreshing ,  I want to make  this with LocalStorage, I searched in stackoverflow for this problem   but none helped me for localstorage,   how can I do this ?
any solution? it will helps me so much

```js
const AddBook = document.querySelector(".AddBook");
let uniqueid = 0;

let cont = document.querySelector(".main");
AddBook.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const bookname = document.querySelector(".bookname").value;
  const authorname = document.querySelector(".author").value;
  let error = document.querySelector(".error");
  if (bookname == "", authorname == '') {
    console.log("Fill the field");

    error.innerHTML = 'Fill all the fields';

  } else {
    error.style.display = "none";
    uniqueid++;
    console.log("Data loaded");
    let newrow = document.createElement("div");
    newrow.setAttribute("class", "row");
    newrow.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    newrow.style.color = "black";

    let newbook = document.createElement("SPAN");
    let remove = document.createElement("button");
    remove.innerHTML = "X";
    remove.addEventListener("click", () => {
      cont.removeChild(newrow);
      console.log("Book is removed");
    })
    let newauthor = document.createElement("SPAN");
    let newid = document.createElement("SPAN");

    newid.innerHTML = uniqueid;

    newrow.appendChild(newbook);
    newrow.appendChild(newauthor);
    newrow.appendChild(newid);

    newrow.appendChild(remove);
    cont.appendChild(newrow);
    localStorage.setItem('newrow', JSON.stringify(bookname, authorname));

    let getbook = localStorage.getItem('newrow', JSON.stringify(bookname));
    let getauthor = localStorage.getItem('newrow', JSON.stringify(authorname));
    console.log(getbook);
    console.log(getauthor);

    newbook.innerHTML = getbook;
    newbook.innerHTML = getauthor;

  }

})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

input {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: crimson;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  min-height: 5vh;
  background-color: crimson;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 25px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.text {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:regular,regular,400,400regular" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>Book App</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder=" Book Name" class="bookname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Author Name" class="author">
    <button class="AddBook">Add Book</button>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="bookinfo">Book Name</span>
        <span class="authorname">Author Name</span>
        <span class="uniqueid">ID</span>
        <span class="authorname">Type</span>

      </div>
      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#example

Comment: what do you mean by 'input results', do you want to store all the input from the users in an array in the local storage.

Comment: yup, I want to save input result on html page even if  website refreshing,